# Integration Using a Function Defined by an Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have to integrate $f(x) = x + \sin(x^2)$ and find $F(x)$ (where the derivative of $F$ is $f$) such that $F(1) = 0$. I know that the antiderivative of $f(x)$ is $(1/2)x^2 + \int_0^x\sin(t^2) dt$, but I have no idea what to do with $F(1)= 0$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem, $F(x)=F(1)+\int_1^x f(s)\,ds$.

Comment: And is f(s) the entire antiderivative, including the x^2 term?

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I still do not understand what is going on.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is as you wrote it in the first sentence. Thus $F(x)=\frac12(x^2-1)+\int_1^x\sin(t^2)\,dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think about what means $F(1)=0$ and how you deal with it.

We know that, given $c\in\Bbb{R}$, $G_c(x)=\int_c^x f(t)\, dt$ is an antiderivative of $f$. Note that $G_c(c)=\int_c^c f(t)\, dt = 0$. So, what number should $c$ be (thinking in $F(1)=0$) ?

Yes, that's right! $c$ must be $1$.

Now, let $F=G_1$ and we are done!